# Regex to extract attribute from html element

Tags: html, regex

Text from stream:

```
<option value=\"1999\">1999</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\
    n    
<option value=\"2000\">2000</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2001\">2001</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2002\">2002</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2003\">2003</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2004\">2004</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2005\">2005</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2006\">2006</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2007\">2007</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2008\">2008</option>\r\n    \r\n \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n    
<option value=\"2009\">2009</option>
```

Regex: `(?si:<option value=\\\"(?<year>.*?)\\)` shouldn't this be the right way to get the year?. meaning for year group, get all characters as long as you don't hit \

Comment: What regex language are you using?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: Generally speaking, using regular expressions on a irregular language like HTML is not a good a good choice. Because although there are parts in HTML that are regular and modern regular expressions implementations support features that are irregular, parsing HTML with regular expressions is difficult and error prone. You should better use a proper HTML parser if the language you are using provides one.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
\<option\svalue\=\\\"(\d*)\\\"
```

This is the plain regex. change it to what language you are using it

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly what language you're using, but try `<option\s+value=(\\\")?(\d+)(\\\")?>`.

Here's it working in Python:

```
>>> re.findall("<option\s+value=(\\\")?(\d+)(\\\")?>", text)
['1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009']
```